# Kubuntu 16.04 lock screen issue

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, hdmi, lock-screen

I have installed Kbuntu 16.04 LTS

- On Intel® Desktop Board DH55TC
- With Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz
- 500 GB SATA hard drive
- Connected to 42" LG TV with HDMI cable
- TP-Link 300 MB USB wireless LAN
- Wireless keyboard & mouse

All drivers are installed properly, display is also nice. All is working fine.

When I fresh install, on time zone I selected Asia and Kuwait as I am living in Kuwait (Middle East). After complete installation my desktop start showing date/time in Arabic and I cannot read Arabic so I when to `System Setting --> Regional Settings --> Formats` I change to United States - American English (en_US) for all options over there. So for the current session everything become English as I wanted.

Now there are two

1. Whenever I reboot my lock screen shows me time in Arabic than after once I logged in than it will start showing in English. Even auto lock screen shows me English.**So how can we change initial lock screen to English rather than Arabic**
2. Second issue, As I told initially that I am using 42" Screen, I have set my resolution to 1360x768 which works file after login but **Login screen is very wide don't show me reboot & shutdown button. And also don't show me dropdown for desktop selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the first issue when I downloaded Kubuntu. What I had to do to fix it was to edit the /etc/default/locale file.

```
    :~$ cat /etc/default/locale
    #  File generated by update-locale
    LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Edit anything that starts with `ar_KW` to `en_US`, and you will be good to go. Please remember that you require root privileges to edit this file.
So, edit it using the command:

`:~$ sudo nano /etc/default/locale`

If you already have root privileges then:

`:~# nano /etc/default/locale`

You can also use any other text editor like vi, vim, gedit and so on.

As for the second issue, I am not sure what may be the cause of the problem. You may have to dive through your display settings and find what is wrong as I have never encountered this issue.